UICollisionBehavior with UIPanGesture to detect collision for jigsaw puzzle app
I am working on a simple jigsaw puzzle application. I already implemented jigsaw creation, basic detection of correct position on the picture.
Now I want to try to handle interactions between puzzle pieces. My puzzle element has 4 segments: top, bottom, left, right, which are UIBezpierPath.
After verifying different possible solutions UIKit Dynamics occurred as a possible solution.
Unluckily I am struggling a lot with bunch of unexpected behaviors.
First of all code sample:
class CanvasView {
private var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
private let dynamicBehavior: UIDynamicItemBehavior
private let collision: UICollisionBehavior

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    self.dynamicBehavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior()
    self.collision = UICollisionBehavior()

    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.collision.collisionDelegate = self
    self.collision.collisionMode = .boundaries
    self.collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
    self.animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self)

    let longpressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress(_:)))
    longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.15
    stackView.addGestureRecognizer(longpressGesture)
    longpressGesture.delegate = self

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePanGesture(_:)))
    workBench.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}

func buildPuzzles() {
    puzzle.buildPuzzles { puzzleElements in
        puzzleElements.enumerated().forEach { (index, puzzleElement) in
            // Puzzle creation loop, insignificant fir this example

            self.activePuzzles[index] = puzzleView
            
            // We store puzzles in stackview and there is a dedicated UILongPress + UIPanGestre recognizer to handle moving it out of the stackTrak
            self.puzzleTray.addArrangedSubview(puzzleView, desiredSize: puzzleView.image?.size ?? .zero)

            self.collision.addItem(puzzleView)
            self.dynamicBehavior.addItem(puzzleView)
        }
        self.animator.addBehavior(self.collision)
    }
}

func prepareViewForReordering(at location: CGPoint) {
    self.actualPuzzle = findClickedImageView(at: location)
    self.snapshotView = self.actualPuzzle?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)

    // Resize View to fit actual size
    if let snapshotView, let actualPuzzle {
        // Some visual effects, scaling the puzzle on pick nothing significant
        {...}

        self.collision.addItem(snapshotView)
        self.dynamicBehavior.addItem(snapshotView)
    } else {
        return
    }

    self.originalPosition = location
}

func dragTheTemporaryView(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let actualPuzzle, let snapshotView else {
        return
    }
    // Drag the temporaryView
    var newLocation = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)

    // Some calculations to detect boundires etc. nothing significant
    {...}
    snapshotView.center = newLocation
    animator.updateItem(usingCurrentState: snapshotView)

    // Some detection to snap to correct place nothing significant
    {...}
    // Reset the translation to avoid cumulative effect
    originalPosition = newLocation
}

func dropTheTemporaryView() {
    guard let actualPuzzle, let snapshotView else { return }

    // Some code to handle putting the puzzle on the board on back into a tray, nothing significant
    {...}
    actualPuzzle.frame = snapshotView.frame
    animator.updateItem(usingCurrentState: actualPuzzle)

    snapshotView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.dynamicBehavior.removeItem(snapshotView)
    self.collision.removeItem(snapshotView)
    self.snapshotView = nil
    self.actualPuzzle = nil
}

@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began:
            let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
            prepareViewForReordering(at: location)
        case .changed:
            dragTheTemporaryView(gestureRecognizer)
        case .ended, .cancelled:
            dropTheTemporaryView()
            // Reenable scroll and gesture recognizer
            gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
        default:
            break
    }
}

@objc func handlePanGesture(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gestureRecognizer.state {
        case .began:
            let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
            prepareViewForReordering(at: location)
        case .changed:
            dragTheTemporaryView(gestureRecognizer)
        case .ended, .cancelled:
            dropTheTemporaryView()
            gestureRecognizer.isEnabled = true
        default: break
    }
}
}

We're working with 2 gesture recognizers. UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UIPanGestureRecognizer. LongPress is responsible for initial item pick-up from the tray (scrollable UIStackView) and PanGesture is responsible for further moving element when it's picked from the board.
My current problem seems to be directly connected with not fully undestanding the UIDynamic kit.

All of my objects seems to be affected by some basic physics/gravity. They fall downwards. I do not care about down-force, bouncing between objects or screen edges.

UIPanGestureRecognizer works correctly however, the objects are rotated. It looks lke  the gravity factor and/or object mass seems to be in action.

Objects when are about to snap into the final position with code below are distorted:
actualPuzzle.frame = snapshotView.frame
actualPuzzle.isHidden = false
animator.updateItem(usingCurrentState: actualPuzzle)





Finally I would like to detect only collisions based on the defined UIBezpierPath edges but prevent the objects of interaction one with another. As an interactions I mean physical collisions, pushing each other away etc. They still should overlap with each other. Collisions are only to determine if objects are neighbours and should they snap.


I doubt you want to use "collision detection" ... based on the image you posted, there would be no way to slide a "knob" into a "socket."

I do not plan to slide knob into socket. I want to add bezpier paths for each side and add some threshold for collider to detect overlapping. That was my first idea. Another one is to just calculate relative distance from the final position and add some threshold. More or less let’s skip the detection part details and try it focus on current problems which I listed there.

OK -- don't know if this will work for you, but... Assuming you are creating the paths and "cutting up the image" at runtime, get the center-point of each path. When the user drags the "piece" so its path's center-point is close enough  (within a defined radius, maybe 10-points), then it has been successfully placed and you can position it exactly.

Actually, I solved it in a simpler way. Each puzzle knows its final position. While panning, I check for frame intersect by iterating over active puzzles. The bounding boxes for intersection checks are slightly larger. When there's a collision: A-Puzzle active (being dragged) and S-Puzzle is stationary. I get S-Puzzle's current position and calculate the x,y offset from its final position, giving a relative offset. This offset is used for A-Puzzle to calculate the distance relative to its neighbor. I'll improve it by storing neighbor references, making intersections robust.

@DonMag more or less, my original questions are still in power. I solved my initial problem by bypassing the use of Colliders however, I would love to know the answers for the main questions: pysics/gravity effect, rotations and not expected interactions while panning, distortions on snapping.

Piotr -- UICollisionBehavior / UIDynamicItemBehavior / etc is probably something you want to investigate and experiment with using a very simple and controlled setup... but, as I mentioned, I doubt you really want that for this task. Glad you found a solution. If you are interested, I put together this quick example that you might find interesting -- and maybe a little helpful moving forward: https://github.com/DonMag/QuickJigsaw
